# How to print dependency tree in Gradle excluding external libraries for easier readability?

Tags: gradle

I'm working on a large multiple project build with many dependencies to external libraries. For me interesting are the internal dependencies, but the the presence of 3rd part libraries makes the dependency tree hard to read.
Let's assume the dependency tree looks like this:

```
+--- project :project-a (*)
\--- project :project-b
     +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
     +--- javax.help:javahelp:2.0.05
     +--- project :project-c
     |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
     |    +--- org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3 (*)
```

Is there an easy way to print the dependency tree, that won't include external libraries, but only dependencies to other projects?
In the example above it could look like this:

```
+--- project :project-a (*)
\--- project :project-b
     +--- project :project-c
```

I have searched for a solution on the internet, but did not found any. The project uses gradle 7.

Comment: How about something like:  `./gradlew dependencies --configuration=runtimeClasspath | grep ' project '`